# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: python

I'm trying to write this little basic piece of code and no matter what I still get this error even though it's what it says in the book I'm trying to read. Can you please help me solve it? I've tried searching and nothing explains the problem.

```
from sys import argv

script = argv
filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print(f"Here's your file {filename}:")
print(txt.read())

print("Type the filename again:")
file_again = input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print(txt_again.read())
```

I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Saman/Desktop/Python_Codes/argv.py", line 6, in <module>
    txt = open(filename)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Comment: `filename = argv` => `filename = argv[2]` if second argument. You're passing a list for both script and filename...

Comment: `argv` is a *list* of all the command-line parameters to your program (with the name of the program itself as the first element).  `argv[1]` is the first of the parameters, which is probably your filename.

Comment: Thank you. But I get a "IndexError: list index out of range" when I run the code now. It's so weird. This code is presented in a book.

Comment: Use `filename = argv[1]` (not `argv[2]`, I think that was a typo in the comment), and make sure you call your script from the command line with something like `python my_script.py my_filename.txt`, passing the filename when you call it.

Comment: I still get "IndexError: list index out of range". I'm gonna move on to next lessons. Thank you guys. I appreciate it very much.
Btw, the book is "Python the hard way".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically, `argv` returns a `list` of all the `parameters` passed in with the name of the `program` from the command line.

So to create a simpler program (`script.py`):

```
from sys import argv

print(argv)
```

and then from the command line, we run it like:

```
python script.py param1 param2
```

and then it will `print`:

```
["script.py", "param1", "param2"]
```

as these are the `parameters` passed in with the `program`, separated by `spaces`.

---

Your program should then be modified to:

```
script, filename = argv
```

or simply:

```
filename = argv[1]
```

and then it will run fine when you run something like:

```
python script.py file.txt
```

from the command line.

Comment: Thank you Joe. I know I can write it in other ways. I just wanted to follow the book's example. This of course works.

Comment: @samanhamidi Please `accept` (*grey* `-->` *green* tick next to the answer). Thank you!

Comment: I did. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @samanhamidi No problem!